# Creating text files using python

Tags: python, file

I have a list in the format:

```
a=["C/C++","Java","Python"]
```

I am trying to create a text file for each element in the list using python as follows:

```
for i in a:
    temp=i+".txt"
    with open(temp,"w") as outfile:
          outfile.write("some value")
```

However am running into issues for the elements off the form "C/C++" as it is trying to interpret that as a dir.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C/C++.txt'
```

How do I overcome this??

Note-if the list element does not contain "/" in it, then the code created files for such elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the problem is fairly simple.
[image: A file name can't contain any of the following characters: /:*?<>|]

So, just change the name to a valid one like `C-C++`

Comment: Besides that, there are many other reserved names (under Windows) like `CON` or `COM2` etc. that are illegal as filenames.

Comment: "facepalm"!! yeah i know about con etc, but since i am working in ubuntu assumed it did not apply to linux distros! my bad!

Comment: @Moontails Check [this out](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/) :)